# sklearn random forest regressor predict -inf when train with negative weights

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using a random forest regressor from the sklearn package. The independent variables(X) I use are demographics, and the dependent variable(y) is supposed to be income. In my training dataset, I have sampling weights, and some(<1%) of them are negative. The negative weights are usually small in their absolute values.

This is what happens:

1. Using default settings, the fitted model sometimes, but not always predicts a "-inf".
2. Switch over to the regression tree, the problem disappears.
3. Try multiple times with fewer trees in the forest, most of the time it is fine, but occasionally the same problem occurs.
4. Dropping all negative weights make the problem disappear.
5. For samples with negative weights, make the weights their absolute value and make the income negative, the problem disappear.

Is it because a specific tree has only samples with negative weights and therefore fails? Does anyone have an idea or solution?

To reproduce the error, use the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

df = pd.DataFrame([[2,1,-1],[2,2,2],[3,3,1]])

weight = df[2]
X = df[[0]]
y = df[1]

t = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10,random_state=0).fit(X,y,weight)
print(t.predict([[1]]))
```

This gives: [inf]

Comment: What should negative weights mean??

Comment: In some cases, they can be produced by methods similar to bootstraps with other constraints. These constraints sometimes require subtracting certain values from weights, and in very rare situations create negative weights. In my case, it is used to calculate variance for survey estimates, but they are used in high-energy physics more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure whether negative sample weights make any sense in the tree construction.  The weights are used to obtain a weighted average in the splitting criterion, so negative weights make the row's contribution to impurity negative, I suppose meaning the tree would prefer to be *more wrong* about its prediction for that row.

The cause of your infinities though is when the bootstrapped sample contains the first row twice and the second row once: the total weight is 0, and so the weighted averages divide by zero.  The "value" at the node becomes `np.inf`, and the impurity at the node `np.nan`.